# How to deploy a spring web application to an apache web server

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-mvc, tomcat

So I'm a complete beginner(started programming 4 months ago) so bear with me please, i have this spring web application with an apache tomcat web server auto installed with it, and it's working quite fine in a local host.

I've bought a server a few days ago and installed the apache2 web server on it, and am currently trying to figure out how to configure my spring application to work as the controller handling any request that's sent to the server, but don't seem to find anything.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by having "bought a server"? The more details the better.

Comment: The answer is _yes, but it's much more trouble than it's worth_. Spring Boot applications can run without having to do any "server" setup, just `java -jar app.jar`.

Comment: Bought a server in a web hosting website and a domain. I don't think am getting your idea right, would putting a standalone copy of my project in one of my server's directories work? If yes can you specify a directory?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a proxy (usually mod_proxy), take a look at [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)

Comment: Would it affect performance if i use this method instead of the mod_jk? And do i have to put my project as a standalone in a specific directory?

Answer (score 0):

There was probably an error while deploying the application to tomcat. I suggest checking the application log.

Comment: My application is working fine with tomcat(in a local host), my problem is with deploying my app on a public server with an apache2 web server.

Comment: ok, I was talking about deploying on public server. Did you generate a WAR file to deploy to the web server? I think that you need a Tomcat Server on your public server..

Comment: No, i actually thought it would work as a jar, so i did some research, and I'm going to uninstall the apache2 and install tomcat, thanks for the help.